# Picture not aligning top?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So in my program i have a layout implemented in which i want the image to alignTop of the parent. I used to exact same layout code for another activity (with minor changes) and it works perfectly but when using it in this activity it does not. My image still aligns to the center fo the view. Here is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkGray"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.intellidev.fuzionvapor.HomeDetails"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_details">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeDetailsActivityImage"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeDetailsActivityImage"
        android:textColor="@color/fuzionRed"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityRuler"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeDetailsActivityTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeDetailsActivityRuler"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/homeDetailsActivityButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivitySizeSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ms_arrowColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
            app:ms_baseColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="true"
            app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/sizeFloatingLabel"
            app:ms_highlightColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_hintColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_hint="Size"
            app:ms_multiline="false"
            app:ms_thickness="1dp" />

        <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityNicotineSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ms_arrowColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
            app:ms_baseColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="true"
            app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/nicotineFloatingLabel"
            app:ms_highlightColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_hintColor="@color/fuzionRed"
            app:ms_multiline="false"
            app:ms_hint="Nicotine"
            app:ms_thickness="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/fuzionRed"
        android:text="Add To Cart"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

to

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailsActivityImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

Comment: Did that. Cleaned and ran build and its still not working

Comment: change android:scaleType="fitCenter" to android:scaleType="fitStart"